# Combination of IIR filter with Hilbert transform

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, filtering, hilbert-transform

I am familiar with the combination of the FIR filter with Hilbert transform, leading to the analytic signal:
$$y_a(t)=y(t)+jH(y(t))=x(t)*h(t)+jH(x(t)*h(t))=x(t)*\left(h(t)+jH\left(h(t)\right)\right)$$
which means that we can define a new complex filter $$g(t)=h(t)+jH\left(h(t)\right)$$ that will represent both filtering and Hilbert transform (analytic signal). Now, is there an equivalent method for IIR filter that will provide a band-pass-based analytic signal?

I was thinking of integrating a FIR filter representing the Hilbert transform into the IIR filter. Not sure that it is the best idea though.

Comment: While you may be able to coerce an IIR to behave like a FIR, a Hilbert transformer as an IIR will be difficult, if not impossible, since an IIR is by definition, non-linear phase. IIRC I stumbled once upon a paper about elliptic Hilbert transformer(?), but take a big grain of salt with this.